# Is there any free API to get building's type by the coordinates

Tags: maps, openstreetmap

Is there any free API to get building's type (subway / apartments / school / etc) by the coordinates? I found http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6 but it seems like all currently running resources with this API either old or have "Request timeout" problem.

What can I use instead? I don't want to know what API is best (I know that it's not related to StackOverflow), but I want to solve my problem with some solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the [main API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6). It is just for *editing* the map, but not for running heavy queries. Instead take a look at the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) and the nice web frontend [overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/).

Here is an [example query shown on overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/6FK) for returning all buildings in the selected area. As already explained by dkiselev, most of the buildings just have the generic [tag](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) *building=yes* while only about 15% have a [more specific tag](http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/building#values).

Answer (score 0):

Try http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim you need Reverse Geocoding API. And type of a building will be encoded in tags. But most of buildings just mapped as building=yes.

Schools for example will be mapped as amenity=school, for other types check OSM wiki http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: Nominatim is not really suited for returning objects around a given coordinate because it will ignore anything for which it doesn't know how to geocode it. Overpass API will be the better solution here.